# issue with create_user.py in django-cms

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-cms

I just started using django-cms and am facing issues. I used virtualenv.please help.The following is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "create_user.py", line 4, in <module>

    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

  File "/home/mayankmodi/SSAD18/Source/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 7, in < module>

    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token

 File "/home/mayankmodi/SSAD18/Source/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>

    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers

  File "/home/mayankmodi/SSAD18/Source/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>

    from django.core.cache import caches

  File "/home/mayankmodi/SSAD18/Source/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>

    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:

  File "/home/mayankmodi/SSAD18/Source/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__

    self._setup(name)

  File "/home/mayankmodi/SSAD18/Source/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup

    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Can somebody tell me which specific files to edit and what edits should i make

Comment: How are you running this management command?

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. About an hour ago I created a Python3.5 venv with `python -m venv venv`, ran `pip install djangocms-installer`, then `djangocms -f -p . mysite`. It's during this last command that an error gets thrown pointing towards `create_user.py`. Running `python create_user.py` will generate the above error, related to the absence of a `CACHES` dict in the project's `settings.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command instead:

```
djangocms -w web
```

This will start the djangocms-installer wizard and run you through various settings, dependencies, and create a superuser for you to log in with. When it finishes, you should have a running instance of django-cms within `./web/`.

You can access the new instance by going into `./web/` and running `runserver` as usual:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Yes this does it. Has there been a recent change? (`Using cached djangocms_installer-0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl`) as [django-cms stable documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/stable/introduction/install.html) has instructions that will cause this error `.../env/bin/python2.7: can't open file 'create_user.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I assume _something_ has changed since I was able to install django-cms with `djangocms -f -p . mysite` just a month or so ago, but I wasn't able to pin down the culprit of this exact problem.

Comment: Hello @IAmKale, does running djangocms -f -p . mysite give you an error with the latest installer version?

Comment: @Paulo how recent is the latest installer? I _was_ getting errors with whatever version was on PyPI on the 21st as per my comment on the original issue above. If a newer version has come out since then I have yet to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem from a few week ago. I assume the new version(djangocms-installer==0.9.x) have problem because when I created a project using default djangocms-installer(==0.9.0) like "djangcms -p . mysite", there was no questions about DB, django version, or etc, then error...

Try old version "pip install djangocms-installer==0.8.x"(x=12,11,10,...)

Now, I am using "djangocms-installer==0.8.12" without any error.